# how to improve use watchify for many files

Tags: javascript, watchify

I use watchify when I change my front code:

> $(NODE_BIN)/watchify $(SRC_PAGE_DIR)/a.js -t babelify -o $(STATIC_PAGE_DIR)/a.js -dv & \
>   $(NODE_BIN)/watchify $(SRC_PAGE_DIR)/b.js -t babelify -o $(STATIC_PAGE_DIR)/b.js -dv & \
>   $(NODE_BIN)/watchify $(SRC_PAGE_DIR)/c.js -t babelify -o $(STATIC_PAGE_DIR)/c.js -dv & \
>   $(NODE_BIN)/watchify $(SRC_PAGE_DIR)/d.js -t babelify -o $(STATIC_PAGE_DIR)/d.js -dv

but it take too much resource, even my mac will too busy to do other work. Asking for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want [Broccoli](https://github.com/broccolijs/broccoli).

Here is an example of setting it up with babel and browserify with multiple package targets: https://gist.github.com/jearle/1f29848b1c09e7548bf3

If you want to watch and output to a directory instead of serve from an express server like `broccoli serve` does, use this module https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-timepiece